# Get the built child of an existant StreamBuilder()

Tags: mobile, flutter, layout, dart, stream-builder

I'm new to Flutter and I'm trying to figure out for a few days how to get the built widget child of a StreamBuilder to make a few changes to the appearance of the widget.

I have a few widgets like this, already built and saved to a List:

```
GestureDetector(
    child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: (bloc as HomeBloc).outCategoriesCardsColors,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return CardSmallSquare(
              title: key,
              size: CardSmallSquare.defaultCardSize,
              iconUrl: categories[key],
              borderColor: snapshot.data[index + 1] ?? Colors.red,
            );
          } else {
            return CardSmallSquare.buildLoadingCard(context);
          }
        }),
    onTap: () {},
  ));
```

Later on I try to access my list with these widgets and access my CardSmallSquare() that is returned by the StreamBuilder, so I could change a few appearance properties at runtime. The idea was doing something like this (this snippet doesn't work):

```
int index = _widgets.indexWhere((widget) {
  CardSmallSquare card = (((widget as GestureDetector).child as StreamBuilder).child as CardSmallSquare);
  if (card.title == "Title") {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

the StreamBuilder.child doesn't exist. I've tried a bunch of things (methods, tricks etc) so far, but none has worked.

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You could reach a child of StreamBuilder, but this is fighting with framework instead of using it.

You could easily make this logic by mutating widget's State and reacting to this change inside your StreamBuilder's child.

Additionally you can do this inside your Bloc to keep everything clean.

This talk from Google IO can help a lot
https://youtu.be/d_m5csmrf7I

Comment: Actually I guess you can't make a StreamBuilder.child (StreamBuilder hasn't this child attribute). I'd really like to be able to do that, btw that's what I was trying to do.. I'm trying to access the CardSmallSquare this way because I want to use this widget for many other places, so I didn't want to pass a specific parameter through the constructor, for example.